# Where do companies announce dividend payouts?

Tags: united-states, dividends

Is there a required report that companies must submit to share upcoming dividend payments? I looked on sec.gov, but couldn't find documents relating to what I'm looking for. I found [this PDF](http://nasdaq.cchwallstreet.com/nasdaq/pdf/nasdaq-issalerts/2011/2011-002.pdf) that suggests it should be filed, I'm just unsure of what I'm actually looking for, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Public companies must abide by SEC rules of fairness and equity in dividend announcements. SEC requires public companies to announce material information publicly in a way that no one can take advantage by trading on non-public information at the expense of other market participants.

Dividends are published in a press release by the company to all investors through the company's website and to the SEC through SEC website in form 8-k. Dividend announcement usually happens at the same time and in the same press release of the company's earnings.

Form 8-k is not exclusive to dividend announcements. Company's file form 8-k to communicate material information to regulators and investors

You can search for all US companies forms on https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised that there's not a single form that is required to publish this information.

Comment: @GlenSolsberry Companies tend to do the minimum work necessary to comply with regulations, and those regulations are written by lawmakers who tend to have interests in companies.

Answer (score -2):

According to [this](http://www.investopedia.com/university/introduction-to-dividends/dividend-dates.asp), companies will send out a financial report to investors announcing dividend payouts.

Comment: I don't see on there where it states that. Can you help me, since I'm struggling today?

Comment: The last sentence under "Date of Record (or Record Date)"